# Java, transfer graph, output as * to every 100

Tags: java, int

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class BatmanBarGraph {
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
//store the amount of each transfer
 // storage for the variable
 int transfer1;
 int transfer2;
 int transfer3;
 int transfer4;
 int transfer5;

 //greet and ask for the transfers
 System.out.println("Good Morning Lucius. Enter Transfers - ");
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

 //plug in the transfer
 System.out.println("Transfer 1");

 //keyboard 
 transfer1 = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Transfer 2");
 transfer2 = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Transfer 3");
 transfer3 = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Transfer 4");
 transfer4 = keyboard.nextInt();

 System.out.println("Transfer 5");
 transfer5 = keyboard.nextInt();



//print a graph, line by line of each transfer
//Every asterisk (“*”) in each bar represents $100. A transfer of $1000 would then have five stars: *****


 //Create another chart for suspicious transactions
 System.out.println("Suspicious transfer chart: ");
 //divides the number we entered by 100
 int Suspicious1 = (transfer1)/100;
 int Suspicious2 = (transfer2)/100;
 int Suspicious3 = (transfer3)/100;
 int Suspicious4 = (transfer4)/100;
 int Suspicious5 = (transfer5)/100;

 System.out.print("Transfer 1:");
 for (int N1 = Suspicious1; N1 > 0; N1--){
     System.out.print("*");
     }

 System.out.print("Transfer 2: ");
 for (int N2 = Suspicious2; N2 > 0; N2--){
     System.out.print("*");
 }
 System.out.print("Transfer 3: ");
 for (int N3 = Suspicious3; N3 > 0; N3--){
     System.out.print("*");
 }

 System.out.print("Transfer 4: ");
 for (int N4 = Suspicious4; N4 > 0; N4--){
     System.out.print("*");
 }

 System.out.print("Transfer 5: ");

 for (int N5 = Suspicious5; N5 > 0; N5--){
     System.out.print("*");
 }
}

}
```

thats my code, the output i get is

```
    Suspicious transfer chart:
```

Transfer 1:*Transfer 2: **Transfer 3: ***Transfer 4: ****Transfer 5: *****

how do i make them like this [image]

Comment: Bit confused. If every asterisk represents $100, wouldn't $1000 be ten stars?

Comment: Side note, it may be time to learn about arrays and loops.

Comment: yes pada, you right, a 1000$ is = to ten *

Comment: The thing with my output(Suspicious transfer chart)
is that when it comes out, the asterisks are printed before the "transfer X"

Comment: @DaniilKim You need to print a new line after you finish printing the asterisks. Also, I recommend using a method for commonly reused code, for example, printing out the asterisks.

Comment: Your question is not very much clear. Can you explain it further?

Comment: Alright, so when you run my program, the suspicious transfer chart will be like this:
      *Transfer 1:
 *****Transfer 2:
    ***Transfer 3:

Comment: and i need those asterisks to be like on the black picture above.(the picture show not what i have but what i desire to have)

Comment: Could you attach an image of your current output?

Comment: @SimplyPanda no no no. Post the output in a code block, don't use an image (this should be done for the desired output as well)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For educational purposes, this code achieves the apparent intent of your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BatmanBarGraph {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Good Morning Lucius. Enter Transfers - ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] transfers = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < transfers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Transfer " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            transfers[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Suspicious transfer chart:");
        for (int i = 0; i < transfers.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("Transfer " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            for (int n = transfers[i] / 100; n > 0; n--) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Primarily, notice that it's using `System.out.print` instead of `println` when printing the "Transfer X: ****" output; this keeps all information for each transfer on the same line. Then at the end of the loop it does a `System.out.println` to move to the next transfer.

The other main difference is obviously that it's using a 5-element array with `for` loops to store the five transfer amounts, instead of storing each in its own variable.

The output of this modified code is (including my input transfer values):

```
Transfer 1: 600
Transfer 2: 1000
Transfer 3: 830
Transfer 4: 420
Transfer 5: 1200

Suspicious transfer chart:
Transfer 1: ******
Transfer 2: **********
Transfer 3: ********
Transfer 4: ****
Transfer 5: ************
```

To show you what this would look like without the array, here's the same code copy-and-paste for two transfers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BatmanBarGraph
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Good Morning Lucius. Enter Transfers - ");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Transfer 1: ");
        int transfer1 = keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Transfer 2: ");
        int transfer2 = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Suspicious transfer chart:");

        System.out.print("Transfer 1: ");
        for (int n = transfer1 / 100; n > 0; n--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Transfer 2: ");
        for (int n = transfer2 / 100; n > 0; n--) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: Listen, Thats a really beautiful code, but my whole point is to use simple code. Is there is a way to make it with no arrays inside the code?

Comment: i edited my code above, and the output i get is 
Suspicious transfer chart: 
Transfer 1:*Transfer 2: **Transfer 3: ***Transfer 4: ****Transfer 5: *****

how do i get it to be above each other? (break and next line doesn't work)

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an example with two transfers. Surely you can figure out how to copy and paste the code for the other three transfers.

Comment: Thats a beautiful work, i got it myself now too! thanks a lot!